# How to convert a JSON string into a JavaScript Object including type checking

Tags: javascript, types, json

For a Javascript project I have an json string converted into a Javascript object. But the type of all my values is 'string' becaus of the JSON parsing. 
Is there any solution to identify the types and let a script convert them into the correct javascript type?

for example

```
//Javascript object for the json decoded string    
var jsonObj = { id: "foo", count: "1" };
```

All the values are of type 'string' but I want count to be seen as a number. Is there a parser to set the correct type or does it need to be done manual in JS?

Comment: Umm. The **JSON type** is a string. If you want it parsed as a JavaScript number, why not make the JSON have a number in the first place? `{ id: "foo", count: 1 };`

Comment: Are you absolutely not able to receive the number types without the quotations? Because that way the hard work will be done for you...

Comment: Also given that Javascript is loosely typed, "count" will be seen as a number if you treat it as such in the code that interacts with it. http://blog.jeremymartin.name/2008/03/understanding-loose-typing-in.html

Comment: the json string comes from yahoo pipes, where I can retrieve the output as JSON, but all the values are strings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a reviver with `JSON.parse`.

[`json2.js`](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js/blob/master/json2.js#L103) describes the reviver thus

> ```
> JSON.parse(text, reviver)
> ```
>
> The optional reviver parameter is a function that can filter and
>   transform the results. It receives each of the keys and values,
>   and its return value is used instead of the original value.
>   If it returns what it received, then the structure is not modified.
>   If it returns undefined then the member is deleted.

So to convert count to a number you might do

```
JSON.parse(myJsonString, function (key, value) {
  return key === "count" ? +value : value;
});
```

so

```
JSON.stringify(JSON.parse('{ "id": "foo", "count": "3" }', function (key, value) {
  return key === "count" ? +value : value;
}));
```

produces

```
{"id":"foo","count":3}
```

EDIT

To handle dates as well, you can

```
JSON.parse(myJsonString, function (key, value) {
  // Don't muck with null, objects or arrays.
  if ("object" === typeof value) { return value; }
  if (key === "count") { return +value; }
  // Unpack keys like "expirationDate" whose value is represented as millis since epoch.
  if (/date$/i.test(key)) { return new Date(+value); }
  // Any other rules can go here.
  return value;
});
```

Comment: A more generic reviver will be `function(k,v){if(isFinite(+v) return +v; else return v;}`, but you may end converting members who should realy be strings into numbers.

Comment: @Prusse, agreed.  The OP suggested a convention associating key names with types, so I assumed one, but your suggestion is a good one when no such convention exists.  It might not work too well with 64 bit keys stored in string form since `isFinite(+"9007199254740993")` is true, but `+"9007199254740993" === 9007199254740992` because JavaScript numbers only have a 52b mantissa.

Comment: This problem will be present in any 64bit number in javascript, this is expected to happen I guess. Even `9007199254740993 === 9007199254740992` returns true given this restrictions.

Comment: @Prusse, My point was that you should not perform a potentially lossy string->number transformation unless you need to manipulate the data as a number.  If you never convert from a string to a number then you never have this problem.

Comment: Hmm, interesting, thanks for the response. So in fact I need to write a function manually to check the types? Will this also work if the original data contains a time or date, for example: Thu, 04 Aug 2011 12:59:50 GMT ? Probably the function will be a little more complex..

Comment: @daFunker, the function runs at parse time.  Yes, you have to write it, but you don't have to handle recursion over the JSON data structure.  See my edit for date handling.

Comment: @mike thanks for the helpfull response. I'm writing the code right now to handle the different data types according to what I need. What does the '+' sign exactly means?

Comment: @dafunker, The `+` prefix operator just coerces its operand to a number.  Think of `+"3"` a similar to `-"3"` but without the negation, so `+(stringThatHoldsANumber)` just tries to convert the value to a number.