# Preserving type when fetching JSON from server

Tags: php, jquery, json

Here's my server side PHP script:

```
echo json_encode(
    array( 
        "1" => "foo",
        "2" => "bar"
    )
);
```

The indexes are strings.

I'm fetching this array through `$.ajax()` with jQuery, and using Chrome's developer tools I can see that it's interpreting the indexes as numeric values and not strings.

How can I preserve that string type when passing the JSON from the server to the client? Or is the concept of type completely lost when transferring JSON data from a server to a client?

Comment: Did you try not put quotes around the 1 and 2.

Comment: What do you mean exactly? The produced JSON is `{"1":"foo","2":"bar"}`. What are you doing with it client-side?

Comment: Also add `header('Content-type: application/json');` before `echo`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6945605/how-to-convert-a-json-string-into-a-javascript-object-including-type-checking

Comment: You can also try `intval(1)`, I have never tried it on the array key but i have done it on the value.

Comment: Does'nt really matter what you do to the PHP array, in json that would be quoted strings anyway. Why would you need them as anything else? On the client side all you have to do is parse it as JSON to get the object back -> `JSON.parse(data);`

Comment: The problem is that Chrome / Opera re-order JSON received from the server by property if the properties are numeric. I know that there is no guarantee of order in an object but a quick and dirty hack is to use strings as the indexes.

Comment: Why would you need order if you have the indices, just do a for loop and get the values in whatever order you like ?

Comment: @adeneo `json_encode(array('key'=>intval(1)))` returns `{'key':1}` no quotes around it.

Comment: @Pitchinnate - yes it does, but that's because you're forcing it, and it's no longer valid JSON.

Comment: @Pitchinnate That returns `{"key":1}`, and `intval(1)` is identical to  just `1`. What's your point?

Comment: Try using the integer as the key, and I'll bet it gets quoted.

Comment: What's the problem here? How are you using the keys?

Comment: @Matthew - I still don't get it, you're sending a string, and receiving a string. To make it into something else would require manual labour on your part, and if you create an object you'll need to get the values somehow anyway ?

Comment: @adeneo - Judging from `using Chrome's developer tools I can see that it's interpreting the indexes as numeric values and not strings`, I'd say he's already doing that step, but because the indexes are numeric string, Chrome is just saying they're numeric.

Comment: I was just saying integers don't get forced to quoted values when they are values, as I said in an early comment I don't know if that is the same case for keys. Some API's require some values come in as integers with no quotes.

Answer (score 1):

Strings can be numeric and strings, and even booleans, thanks to type coercion and duck typing (if it looks, walks, and quacks like a duck, it is a duck), since both are loosely typed languages. You should be just fine handling it like a string.

In the case of Chrome developer tools, you have a string that consists only of numeric characters. Therefore, it's also a numeric data type (it "looks like a duck").

Perhaps if you explain what, exactly, it is you're doing that isn't working, we could help you with a better way.

Comment: Dynamic type conversions ("weak typing") is not the same as "no concept of type". There are very well types in both PHP and JS.

Comment: @deceze - I chose my wording because of the OP's original wording - "Or is the concept of type completely lost when transferring JSON data from a server to a client?" but there, I've edited it.

Comment: So the answer is *no*, the concept is not lost. Type coercion rules still apply as usual depending on the context.

Comment: @deceze - which is why I removed that line.

Answer (score 0):

<strike>This is because in PHP, what javaScript calls an object is an array in php. In JavaScript, array indexes cannot be strings, they must be positive integers.</strike>

If you want JavaScript to interpret that as an array, give it a 0 index and make the indexes integers rather than strings.

Your code already does what you want it to do. The keys are strings.

http://jsfiddle.net/XC85h/

```
var jsonStr = '{"1":"foo","2":"bar"}';

var obj = JSON.parse(jsonStr);

for (key in obj) {
    console.log(typeof key, key); // string 1, string 2
}​
```

Edit (per comments)
**Never rely on the sort order of a JavaScript object, it may vary between browsers.**

Comment: I don't want jQuery to interpret it as an array; I want jQuery to interpret it as an object with strings like "1" and "2" as their properties.

Comment: @Matthew What exactly is php returning, i would expect it to be `{"1":"foo","2":"bar"}`

Comment: There is such a thing as an object in PHP, and it's not the same as an array ?

Comment: Sure, but that's not what we're dealing with here.

Comment: @Kevin B: regarding your updated answer, you are creating that object in Javascript. My question is how to preserve that type when receiving the JSON from a server, in this case a PHP script echoing back JSON.

Comment: @Matthew No, i'm doing EXACTLY what you are doing. PHP returns a string, such as my jsonstring variable contains. jQuery then parses it with JSON.parse, just like i am doing. Please read my last note too, it is very important to what you are trying to do.

Comment: JSON is a data format, it is NOT an object, neither is it an array. If you want an object, make an object from the returned string (which is in JSON format, and perfect for creating an object).